# wp_query by meta key

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written this loop to pull in posts that get the most views within the last 30 days (logging the view count to the DB as a custom meta key).

Though, upon thinking about it a little more I'm not really sure if I'm going about it the 'right' way, or at least the most logical way.

```
<?php 

                // Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
                function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
                    // posts in the last 30 days
                    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
                    return $where;
                }

                add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

                    $popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 
                'posts_per_page' => 33, 
                'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
                'order' => 'DESC'  

                ) );


                remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); ?>


                <?php if ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : ?>



                <?php while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post(); ?>

            <article <?php post_class('item-post block'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title (); ?>
            </article> <!-- end div post -->


                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

So, as you can see I'm limiting the date range to 30 days, ordering the posts by the meta_value_num and getting 33 posts.

So, logically what's happening is any post published within the last 30 days will be displayed here in order of how many views they've had. 
What got me thinking about it is when I created a page to pull the 33 most viewed posts from the last 7 days, they're the same. Obviously.

So I think what I want to be doing is getting posts by how many views they've had IN the last 30 days/7 days, not posts published within those date ranges.

Am I thinking along the right lines? If so, can you give me any idea of how to go about that?

Comment: Actually it's confusing, you want 30 most viewed post that's fine, but within a date range or without any date range?
Without date range you'll get posts with highest views at anytime.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the WordPress 3.7 or later, you now can use [`date_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters). Not tested, but your query will look something like:

```
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 33,
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
      array(
        'after' => '1 month ago',
        'column' => 'post_date_gmt', //posted within one month
      ),
    )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
```

strtotime('30 days') = now + 30 days

Comment: Can you explain your answer please?

Comment: your [function filter_where] use the wrong date calculation. It suppose to be [strtotime('-30 days')], if you are looking for past 30 days posts. [strtotime('30 days')] means future 30 days.

Comment: Ah yes yes, it actually is -30, I just pasted it in wrongly when I was writing the post. But the point is still the same, this still retrieves posts from the last 30 days, not necessarily those posts which have received the most views over the last 30 days. For example, something might have had more views and been posted 31 days ago.

Comment: In that case, I do not think you write wp_query properly. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters
Example: `'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key' => 'color',
   'value' => 'blue',
   'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
  )
 )`

Comment: Yup, that was sort of my question, I'm not sure how to go about building that query.

Comment: Have you tried remove `'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ` ; can you retrieve posts? BTW, you can always put `define('SAVEQUERIES', true);` in wp-config.php to enable sql query inspect, it would give you a better idea about the query.

Comment: If I remove the parameters then it just gets the 33 most recent posts, not in order of views. I want them in order of views (which it's doing at the moment) but only views logged in the last 30 days. At the moment it retrieves them in order of views but only posts published in the last 30 days. Make sense?

Comment: If you try to retrieve post by viewed last 30/7 days, not published last 30/7 days, you plugin (whatever creates the meta-key [wpb_post_views_count]) needs to add extra meta-key to log the lastest view in day time. Then, you can use `'meta_query' => array( array(), array() ...)`; Hope I do not misunderstand the quiz.